# What data does the mobile app send to a Bluetooth LE electro-stimulation device?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have a Bluetooth LE electrostimulation device that connects to a mobile app and the app sends data to the device to start doing the electrical pulse,
I have the mobile application code (native android),
The question is: can I know what data the mobile app sends when I press a button responsible for the burst?
The goal is to create another app with Flutter that does the same processing as the Android app I have.

Comment: If you have the application code, why don't you look it up inside the code? If this does not work for you try to get yourself a BLE sniffer like the one from [Nordic Semiconductor](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Sniffer-for-Bluetooth-LE). The cheapest option would be to use a [nRF52840 Dongle](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-hardware/nRF52840-Dongle), flash the sniffer firmware and use it with wireshark. [Here](https://jimmywongiot.com/2020/07/08/how-to-install-nrf-sniffer-through-nrf52-dk-board/) is a tutorial on how to do this

Comment: The best place to start is with the device documentation. Second is the original app source code. Third is the official BLE standard documentation. Fourth would be the sniffer solution. I assume you need to set up the device as well before starting the electro stuff. That could mean 2 to 6 times of query and response with the device to be able to start. Using a sniffer it will be difficult to see what is what in the stream of Bytes. Hopefully the device is implementing official BLE and you could work with that.